# Edit entire column in dataframe based on value in last row of that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and I want to set the entire value of the column to 0 if the value in the last row of that column is <0.
The current code i have is:

```
ccy.loc[(ccy['CumProfit'].iloc[-1] < 0), 'CumProfit'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if`:

```
if (ccy['CumProfit'].iloc[-1] < 0):
    ccy['CumProfit'] = 0
```

Or `if-else` for one line solution:

```
ccy['CumProfit'] = ccy['CumProfit'] if ccy['CumProfit'].iloc[-1] < 0 else 0
```